# Вывод данных из других таблиц в один массив

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5

У меня сайт с поиском билетов, в таблице tickets хранится информация: дата; из какого города (идинтификатор) в город (идинтификатор)
Но у меня также есть отдельная таблица с городами (идинтификатор, название_города)

Вывод: мне нужно выводить в каждый город название по идинтификатору, но я не знаю как добавить название города в массив($result) с данными чтобы в вюхе вывести

```
public function search(){
        // Sets the parameters from the get request to the variables.
        $fromCityName = Request::get('from');
        $toCityName   = Request::get('to');
        $date         = Request::get('date');

        $from_id   = City::where('name', $fromCityName)->pluck('id');
        $to_id     = City::where('name', $toCityName)->pluck('id');

        $result = Tickets::select(DB::raw("*"))
            ->where('from_city_id', '=', $from_id)
            ->where('to_city_id', '=', $to_id)
            ->where('date', '=', $date)
            ->get();

        return view('index.search', ['tickets' => $result]);
}
```

Вюха:

```
@foreach ($tickets as $ticket)
    From city id: {{ $ticket->from_city_id }}
    To city id: {{ $ticket->to_city_id }}
    Date: {{ $ticket->date }}
    From city name
    To city name:
@endforeach
```

Буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень просто

```
$result = \DB::table('tickets')
        ->select('tickets.*', 'city.name as city_name','city.id as city_id')
        ->leftJoin('city', 'city.id', '=', 'tickets.city_id')
        ->where('а здесь твои условия')
        ->get();
```

А в вюхе выводиш таким образом

```
@foreach($result as $item)
city id: {{ $item->city_id }}
city name: {{ $item->city_name }}
date: {{ $ticket->date }}
......
@endforeach
```

Comment: спасибо! попробую

Comment: Спасибоо!! сработало, но как мне еще добавить вместо одного city_name на две колонки: from_city_name и to_city_name? буду благодарен

Comment: напиши структуру своих таблиц или скриншот сделай, а то я не полностью понимаю

Comment: \DB::table('tickets')
            ->select(
                'tickets.*',
                'c2.name as city_to_name',
                'c.name as city_from_name')
            ->leftJoin('city as c', 'c.id', '=', 'tickets.from_city_id')
            ->leftJoin('city as c2', 'c2.id', '=', 'tickets.to_city_id')
            ->where('tickets.date', '=', '2017-10-04 00:00:00')
            ->orderBy('tickets.id')
            ->get(); вот пример рабочего запроса, на сколько я понял. Суть в том, чтобы таблице city дать псевдоним и обратится к ней 2 раза через leftJoin

Comment: спасибо!











lorem ispum dolor